# Angular 8 MatDialog await the result to continue

Tags: angular, dialog

I'm parsing excel sheets but If there are more than just 1 sheet the user needs to choose. I want to do this with a dialog and the function needs to wait until the result is there.

My code:

app.component.ts:

```js
onFileSelected(file: File): void {
       const reader: FileReader = new FileReader();
       reader.onload = async (e: any) => {
         // read workbook
         const bstr: string = e.target.result;
         const wb: XLSX.WorkBook = XLSX.read(bstr, {
           type: "binary",
           sheetRows: 101
         });

         this.sheetNames = wb.SheetNames;

         if (this.sheetNames.length > 1) {
           console.log("größer eins");
           await this.openDialog();
         }
         // grab first sheet
         const wsname: string = wb.SheetNames[this.sheetIndex];
         const ws: XLSX.WorkSheet = wb.Sheets[wsname];

         this.data = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(ws, { header: 0 });
       };
       reader.readAsBinaryString(this.uploadComponent.file);
}

openDialog(): void {
 const dialogRef = this.chooseSheetDialog.open(ChooseSheetDialogComponent, {
   width: "500px",
   data: { sheets: this.sheetNames }
 });

 dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
   console.log("The dialog was closed " + result);
   this.sheetIndex = result;
 });
}
```

It's a shortened form.

The dialog.ts:

```js
 export class ChooseSheetDialogComponent {
   selectFormControl = new FormControl("", Validators.required);
   constructor(
     @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) private data: any,
     public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<ChooseSheetDialogComponent>
   ) {}

   onNoClick(): void {
     this.dialogRef.close();
   }
 }
```

dialog.html:

```html
<h1 mat-dialog-title>Wähle aus</h1>
<div mat-dialog-content>
<p>Es existieren mehrere Arbeitsblätter / Tabellen. Bitte wähle.</p>
<mat-form-field>
 <mat-label>Favorite sheet</mat-label>
 <mat-select required [formControl]="selectFormControl">
   <mat-option *ngFor="let sheet of data.sheets" [value]="sheet">
     {{sheet}}
   </mat-option>
 </mat-select>
 <mat-error *ngIf="selectFormControl.hasError('required')">
   This field is required
 </mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
</div>
<div mat-dialog-actions>
<button mat-button (click)="onNoClick()">No Thanks</button>
<button mat-button [mat-dialog-close]="selectFormControl.value" cdkFocusInitial>Ok</button>
</div>
```

But yes however `await this.openDialog();` does not work. Error in the browser:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property '!ref' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property '!ref' of undefined
    at AppComponent.getExcelHeaderRow (app.component.ts:121)
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `toPromise` function in order to have a Promise-oriented logic. Also, the function must return a `Promise` so that you can use `await` later:

```js
async openDialog(): Promise<number> {
 const dialogRef = this.chooseSheetDialog.open(ChooseSheetDialogComponent, {
   width: "500px",
   data: { sheets: this.sheetNames }
 });

 return dialogRef.afterClosed()
   .toPromise() // here you have a Promise instead an Observable
   .then(result => {
      console.log("The dialog was closed " + result);
      this.sheetIndex = result;
      return Promise.resolve(result); // will return a Promise here
   });
}
```

Then, your `onFileSelected` function can use `await` as follows:

```js
async onFileSelected(file: File): void {
    const result = await this.openDialog(); // waiting here
    console.log('result', result); // you got the value
}
```

Also, I wrote a working sample [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-dialog-promise-await). Don't forget to open the browser's console to see the results.

I hope it helps!

Comment: Works like a charm! How many times I can say thank you,,, I'm not good when it comes to async problems. But this solution now I will remember also for other problems. Nice work!

Comment: thanks, you forgot to add the onFileSelected() function must be marked as async too to be able to use await inside of it

Comment: Thanks for stackblitz @luixaviles. Help a lot!

Comment: can you return void on async funciton?

Comment: toPromise() is depracated

Comment: I added a answer which doesn't make use of toPromise @VasilValchev

Answer (score 1):

I was running into the same issue and also found .toPromise() being deprecated.
Looking at the documentation I rewrote some of the above code to make use of: `firstValueFrom`

Keep in mind to upgrade to rxjs 7: [Module '"rxjs"' has no exported member 'firstValueFrom'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72253499/module-rxjs-has-no-exported-member-firstvaluefrom?answertab=trending#tab-top)

Above answer can be rewritten a bit like this:

`import { firstValueFrom } from 'rxjs';`

```
async openDialog(): Promise<number> {
 const dialogRef = this.chooseSheetDialog.open(ChooseSheetDialogComponent, {
   width: "500px",
   data: { sheets: this.sheetNames }
 });

 return await firstValueFrom(dialogRef.afterClosed())
   .then(result => {
      console.log("The dialog was closed " + result);
      this.sheetIndex = result;
      return Promise.resolve(result); // will return a Promise here
   });
}
```

The await could be redundant.