# Module '"rxjs"' has no exported member 'firstValueFrom'

Tags: node.js, angularjs, rxjs, nestjs

App.service file looks like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { HttpService } from '@nestjs/axios';
import { Observable, firstValueFrom } from 'rxjs';
// import { firstValueFrom } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class AppService {
  constructor(private httpService: HttpService) {}
  async getWeatherForecasts() {
    const url =
      'http://www.7timer.info/bin/api.pl?lon=113.17&lat=23.09&product=astro&output=json';
    const { data } = await firstValueFrom(this.httpService.get(url));
    return data;
  }
}
```

Package.json File looks like this:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@fmr-pr103625/nest-scaffold": "^1.5.5",
    "@nestjs/apollo": "^10.0.9",
    "@nestjs/axios": "0.0.7",
    "@nestjs/common": "^7.6.18",
    "@nestjs/core": "^7.6.18",
    "@nestjs/graphql": "^10.0.9",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^7.6.18",
    "apollo-server-express": "^3.6.7",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "graphql": "^16.3.0",
    "graphql-tools": "^8.2.8",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^3.0.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.10",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.6.7",
    "ts-morph": "^14.0.0"
  },
```

-----------------**********************--------------------------------

I am not able to import firstValueForm from rxjs.

Things i already tried:

1. to downgrade the version of rxjs  from 6.

Comment: looks like `firstValueForm` is available on rxjs v7.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`firstValueFrom` introduce in `Rxjs 7` as a replacement of `toPromise`

[RxJS 6.x to 7.x Detailed Change List](https://rxjs.dev/6-to-7-change-summary#rxjs-6x-to-7x-detailed-change-list)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using TypeScript, make sure your tsconfig.json configuration is correct and compatible with the ECMAScript features you're using. Particularly check the module, target, and lib options.

For example, your tsconfig.json might look similar to this (adjust as needed for your project):

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "esnext",
    "target": "es2015",
    "lib": ["es2018", "dom"]
  }
}
```